# Are there builtin parameters for AppPool shutdown executable parameters

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pool

When using IIS Application Pools in Rapid-Fail protection mode an executable can be called on failure.  What builtin parameters are available?

[image]

So for instance a call to re-balance the load balancer with the IP and hostheader of the website that just shutdown?

is there something like this?

`c:\temp\lbsdk.exe {IP} {hostheader} {identity}`

The documentation makes no mention of any such builtins.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post, but I was looking up the same question and I found this blog post: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Dec/19/IIS-7-and-Rapid-Fail-Protection

According to the last comment (Cees meuleman February 24, 2012 @ 3:14am)

He used the following to have the application-pool automatically reset.

```
Shutdown executable: c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Appcmd.exe
Shutdown parameters: start APPPOOL <your website>
```

Alternatively you can choose to do an iisreset and if that fails a server reboot:

```
Shutdown executable: c:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe
Shutdown parameters: /rebootonerror
```